# kak-lsp Log shows `Language server is not initialized`

Tags: language-server-protocol, kakoune

I have installed kak-lsp successfully with `plug.kak`. I have placed the `kak-lsp.toml` in `~/.config/kak-lsp/kak-lsp.toml`. For the rustlang part it looks like this:

```rs
[language.rust]
filetypes = ["rust"]
roots = ["Cargo.toml"]
command = "sh"
args = ["-c", "if command -v rustup >/dev/null; then $(rustup which rls); else rls; fi"]
```

However, when I launch kakoune, it doesn't autocomplete or anything, except it only shows warning for unused variables(and stuff like this). So I turned on the logs, and it gave me this output:

```rs
Jun 30 04:29:35.209 DEBG Language server is not initialized, parking request, module: kak_lsp::controller:100
```

The full log is [here](https://pastebin.com/Pd6svYwp)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your log contains

```
lsp-handle-progress 'Building'
```

This means that rls is just not fully ready yet. It needs to build the entire crate to find all references. This can take a few minutes, depending on the size of your project. The result will be cached in `target/rls`, so it will be much faster on subsequent launches.

Note that the default implementation of lsp-handle-progress doesn't do anything. You can override it to show messages with `echo` or `info`.